# Phonegap Build - open external link in webview

Tags: cordova, hyperlink, webview, phonegap-build, inappbrowser

I loaded a webpage in my app using

```
window.location.href="http://www.webpage.com";
```

Now I want to open a link in the browser, but since I'm in webview my phone ignores `window.open('http://webpage.com', '_system', 'location=yes');` and opens the link in webview...

How can I fix this (using PhoneGap Build) ?

> The funny thing is, "_blank" works when using ajax, but  in my case the
>   output is not accurate as when using webview - I need a solution with webview and to over ride it.

My config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.me.me"
        versionCode = "10" 
        version     = "1.0.0" >                  <icon src="icon.png" />

<icon src="icon-60@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />



        <name>App</name>

<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" version="1.0.0" />


<access origin="*" />

<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true"/>
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />



<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>



</widget>
```

Comment: can you talk more about what you need. There are several solutions and directions for your issue.

Comment: I have a webpage in webview. On that webpage I want to open a link on user's browser..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Atartica,
Okay. Thanks. Now that you have the InAppBrowser installed, the rest of the pieces need to be installed.

- **#1 You will need to set the version for your compiler**, otherwise you will get a similar problem in the future.
- **#2 You will need to learn more about Cordova/Phonegap.** At this point, you are taking stabs in the dark. FWIW, I don't get paid for this. That means if someone gets short with you, it is because you *appear* not to be listening.

**Below is what you need to know** -- Best of Luck, Ask more questions, if you need to.

---

### 1. No support for iOS9 YET!

**PhoneGap Build iOS 9 Support Status**

- Sept 23, 2015
- http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap-build-ios-9-support-status
- Top line: iOS 9 is **NOT** officially supported until Cordova-iOS 4.0.0, which the Cordova team is hard at work on. However some issues can be solved with some simple configuration changes.

  Regardless, of what you are using, as the forum post states, iOS 9 is not officially supported until Cordova-iOS 4.0.0. This means, if you encounter a bug, you must - create a work around, or wait until it is officially supported, *OR* file a bug report with cordova, *OR* wait until someone else creates a work around.

  As for when iOS9 will be supported, my *personal* guess is it will be soon. No more than 30 days. There are alot of complaints about this. The Cordova team is listening.

### 2. Not setting compiler version

From the *Phonegap Build* Forum, [Petra Adds](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/no-support-for-ios9-yet#reply_16160589):

> I would add: without announcement, PGB changed the default PGB-version from 3.7.0 to cli-5.2.0. This causes all those who have not set 'phonegap-version' in config.xml to be confronted with the sudden need of splashscreen and whitelist plugins and additional whitelisting specifications in config and html.
>
> Also, several plugins seem not to build correctly with cli-5.2.0, causing log file error messages about "Class ***.java".

FWIW: *Phonegap Build* [admitted to as much in this tweet](https://twitter.com/jessemonroy650/status/648313365505310720)

From [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) you have hit:

- #6 **Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**
- #7 **Not setting "version" for you plugins**
- #10 **Not adding the new "white-list" and "white-list plugin" parameters in config.xml.**

For #6 & #7

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading error.
>
> Luckily for all of us, Holly Schinsky has written a nice blog post to explain it all:
>
> *Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
> http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

For #10

> This relatively * NEW * requirement means – to access ANY website or resources on the web, you MUST use the whitelist and the whitelist plugin. This requirement goes into affect, if you are using cordova-android@4.0.0 or better; including cli-5.1.1. If however, your version is before 4.0.0, let use say 3.5.0 or 3.7.0, then you will *not* have to add the *white-list* requirement.
>
> To be clear, the "whitelist" has been around for a bit, but the plugin and requirement is very new. As you would expect, when the "whitelist" was added, the defacto open-access feature was deprecated. Or said another way, the defacto open-access feature was planned and scheduled to be eliminated. This change marks a step in removal of the open-access feature.
>
> In addition, the Content Security Policy (CSP) has caught numerous developers - because it was soooo poorly publicized. This CSP needs to go in every single HTML page you used, just like you have to wait for 'deviceready'. The documentation is buried in the bottom of many of the latest documentation pages.

**Related Links**

> Phonegap Build Forum: [Notes for upgrading to cli-5.1.1 on PGB](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/notes-for-upgrading-to-cli-5-1-1-on-pgb) and now required Whitelist
>
> - [Cordova Whitelist Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html)
> - [Phonegap Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)
> - [Phonegap Build Whitelist Guide](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements)

Comment: Hi, you are awesome! Thank you! Question: I set up notifications using "local-notification" plugin. I need to load/check news while the app is closed... How can I do that? I've tried "setInterval" but since the app is closed, everything stops working... and no ajax is sent

Comment: Don't know. I'm not using *local-notification* yet. Try posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

@Atartica,
Based on your last response, I'd say you want to use the InAppBroswer.

First, this is based on using *Phonegap Build*, not Cordova. There is a difference.

- Here are [the plugins](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins)
- Here are [the CoRE plugins](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/core)
- Here is the [link to the Plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1169).
- Here is the [link to the Documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/8ce6b497fa803936784629187e9c66ebaddfbe1b/doc/index.md). (NOTE: This change from version to version.)

**Please note**, for the most part, this will work as expected. BUT If you do NOT set the version to you compiler, you will get the latest version AND you will be required to use the *white-list*, the *plugin*, and the *CSP*.

Here are the details – [Current Tripping Points to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/current-tripping-points.md), See item **2. Not setting compiler version**.

Comment: Hi, I do have plugins set up, and i've tested it when I load webpage using ajax. But when I load it using "window.location.href" or "window.open", all of my links open in webview instead of safari...

Comment: @Atartica, your original post said *nothing* about using a plugin. This is also the first suggestion of using iOS. Perhaps now you'll see why your question is being knocked down a point. -- Please post your `config.xml`. Please state what your target OS is, and what version of OS you are using (ie. Android 5.x, iOS 8.x or 9.x, etc.)

Comment: Right now, I have the app installed on ios